# Performance improvement of of HttpResponseMessage client.SendAsync in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-webapi

I have code like following

```
public async Task<object> GetMethod()

    {

        object result = null;

     HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "www.fo");                    

     HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);

            if (ok)

            {
                dynamic data = JObject.Parse(responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

                result = data.result.paameter1.tables.paamete2.row.ToString();
            }

      return result

     }
```

Observation is client.SendAsync(requestMessage); takes too much time , is there any other better way of doing it considering performance ?

Comment: Is your endpoint response just slow?  How have you isolated that the issue is client.sendasync?

Comment: " takes too much time" . Relative to what?

Comment: Separately, you should not use `.Result`. Your code should have: `dynamic data = JObject.Parse(await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());`

Comment: while debugging also ....it takes few seconds to go ahead....i want to know is there any other way to achieve it ...?

Comment: `i am not sure about endpoint response....but wait it too much` It is important to know where the time is being spent. Going shopping takes me too much time - but trying to optimise the time it takes me to walk to my car before driving to the shops is not fruitful. Since the walking is such a small proportion of the overall time.

Comment: This is pretty much the minimal amount of code to do an HTTP request using HttpClient. If it's too slow, it's likely to either be poor network performance or poor performance of the remote service.

Comment: If you use Postman to submit to that endpoint, how long does it take to see a response there? Note that any vague answer is not useful. **Exact time in milliseconds**.

Answer (score -1):

this would be better

```
private async Task<T> Post<T>(string url, object obj) where T : class
{
    var jsonString = _jsonHelper.SerializeObject(obj);
    var stringContent = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(url, stringContent).ConfigureAwait(false);
    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    if(!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        //throw
    }
    var responseObj = _jsonHelper.DeserializeObject<T>(responseString);
    return responseObj;
}
```

usage

```
public Task<SomeTypedObject> DoSomething(int someValue)
{
    var url = "someUrl";
    var requestObject= new ClassForRequest { proptery1 = someValue};
    return Post<SomeTypedObject>(url, requestObject);
}
```

the main issue with yours i not using await on ReadAsStringAsync, ur is thread blocking.
but i highly suspect this is not the reason for the "performance" you are wanting.

- What is the call doing?
- how much data is it returning?
- how far is the endpoint?/ how powerful is the endpoint machine? / what its ping to that machine?

**PS, show your HttpClient life-time, the problem is most likely there.**

is performance for you how long it takes for 1 request or its ability to do  this x times a minute.